# Jquery menu mouseout/mousemove close issue jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mousemove

I have been working on this menu where you can rollover links and have content id# appear on the right side of the menu. I have it setup for when mousemove outside of div wrapper to close content but I notice if somebody moves the mouse really fast the jquery calculation freeze once outer wrapper div so the menu content gets stuck on last rollover link. If somebody can help me bug this issue with simple logic that would be great.

See jsfiddle.net/ifelse/Qp7XC/

Thanks...

Comment: Can you just use an existing menu like jQuery UI menu instead of having to write your own? Check out http://jqueryui.com/menu/.

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code. And they must be links.

Comment: Interesting but was going for custom feel more control something like the amazon style menu. I guess this can be customize like that but since I made it this far do you have any quick logic for the one I posted?

Comment: How would I do that? "Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your example, the content just gets stuck if you move the pointer in a horizontal line. The problem is that you `<li>` is taking the width of the whole line, so the `onmouseout` event wont fire. Do the li smaller and this should work.